# Android disable HDMI output?

Tags: android, hdmi

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way for me to block HDMI output when my application is running on Android? I need to support minimum API 17 (Android 4.2).

Is there such method I can call to control (hide/show) HDMI output?

```
/sys/class/switch/hdmi/state
```

this file value changes depending on the state of the HDMI

`1` for HDMI connected
`0` for HDMI disconnected

Can I do something with that?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, as eg. The Sky Go app and other TV apps do this. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22778075/android-disable-hdmi and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061621/how-do-i-disable-hdmi-port-of-a-android-device-without-rooting-it I have no experience with this though.

Comment: Presentation API only allows allows you to show different content on the presentation display (HDMI display). I didn't see any way to actually disable the HDMI display. Both of those solutions are same and they both use DisplayManager with Presentation API. Thanks for the idea tho. It's interesting

Comment: try this ans http://stackoverflow.com/a/23025495/3678308

Comment: Have a look at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation.html

Comment: Do you have any luck in HDMI controlling? It is very important in my task!